# How to handle (catch) io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Unable to resolve host

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

Consider the following non-blocking bidirectional streaming gRPC call:

```
this.channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("NoSuchServer", 12345))
              .usePlaintext()
              .build();

this.kvStore = KVStoreServiceGrpc.newStub(channel);
this.executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

this.executor.submit(() -> {
       // This try-and-catch is my failed attempt at handling StatusRuntimeException
       try {
         this.toServer = kvStore.connect(new StreamObserver<KVMessage>() {

              @Override
              public void onNext(KVMessage resp) {
                      lock.lock();
                      response = resp;
                      responseReceived.signalAll();
                      lock.unlock();
              }
            /* Implementation for `onError` and `onCompletedd` redacted */
        });
           Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (StatusRuntimeException e) {
               // Never caught!
                System.err.println("*** FAILED TO CONNECT TO SERVER!!! ***");
        }
        gate.countDown();
});
```

The above code will cause a `StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Unable to resolve host NoSuchServer`, as with any unresolvable host:

```
$ java -jar m1-client.jar
Command> connect NoSuchServer 12345
Mar 04, 2024 3:14:24 P.M. io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener handleErrorInSyncContext
WARNING: [Channel<1>: (NoSuchServer:12345)] Failed to resolve name. status=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host NoSuchServer, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: NoSuchServer: Name or service not known
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:223)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.doResolve(DnsNameResolver.java:282)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:318)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: NoSuchServer: Name or service not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:52)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformResolver.lookupByName(InetAddress.java:1059)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1673)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:1003)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1663)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1528)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:632)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:219)
    ... 5 more
}
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Unable to resolve host NoSuchServer
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:481)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:489)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.drainPendingCallbacks(DelayedClientCall.java:528)
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$1DrainListenerRunnable.runInContext(DelayedClientCall.java:317)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: NoSuchServer: Name or service not known
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:223)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.doResolve(DnsNameResolver.java:282)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:318)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: NoSuchServer: Name or service not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:52)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformResolver.lookupByName(InetAddress.java:1059)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1673)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:1003)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1663)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1528)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:632)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:219)
```

*(Note:  First thread dump is from the logger, which can be turned off; but that's a separate discussion)*

It appears that the `StatusRuntimeException` is thrown from internal lib calls (perhaps as an async task at inner levels).
Unlike with *blocking* gRPC calls, which the client application can catch exceptions thrown from lower levels using a try-and-catch in the above manner, I cannot do the same for *non-blocking* gRPC calls.

**How can I catch `StatusRuntimeException`s at the app level?**

*P.S. I've searched high and low for an answer and thought that there'd be a simple way to handle exceptions (in general) that are thrown from internal lib calls, but these "internal exceptions" don't seem to propagate their way up to the app level.*

Answer (score 2):

grpc-java's internals don't throw. Instead they report back a `Status`. For blocking stubs, that status is converted into a `StatusRuntimeException` and thrown. For async stubs, it is also converted into an exception, but is delivered to `onError(Throwable)` *as an argument*.

```java
this.toServer = kvStore.connect(new StreamObserver<KVMessage>() {
     @Override
     public void onNext(KVMessage resp) {
         lock.lock();
         response = resp;
         responseReceived.signalAll();
         lock.unlock();
     }

     @Override
     public void onError(Throwable t) {
         Status status = Status.fromThrowable(t);
         // This is the equivalent of the catch block for blocking stubs.
         // Do custom error handling here.
         System.err.println("*** FAILED TO CONNECT TO SERVER!!! ***");
     }
     /* Implementation for `onCompleted` redacted */
});
```

For more information, see the `asyncCall()` function of the [error handling example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/errorhandling/ErrorHandlingClient.java).

Comment: Thanks Eric!  Apart from that example, where else is this information --- particularly, the delivery of exceptions to `onError(Throwable)` for async stubs ---  documented?

While I did come that error handling example, I didn't look too deep into it because 1) I was unaware of the redirection of exceptions to `onError(Throwable)` and 2) It says in the comment that the example is about "extract error information from a *server response*."

Comment: s/come/come across/

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are looking for, but did you see the [StreamObserver documentation](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/StreamObserver.html#onError(java.lang.Throwable))?

Comment: With the async stub, `kvStore.connect()` returns immediately. There's no place to throw an exception.

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/pull/10983 to change the comment.